# React: Passing up data from child component into parent does not update values in parent

Tags: reactjs, state, parent-child

// Edit --

This may help:
[Project Hatchways](https://github.com/kel7774/hatchways-app)

Link to issue -
[Issue](https://github.com/kel7774/hatchways-app/issues/6)

As the codes stands right now, the results from the tags still aren't rendering results.

I have a component App.js that renders some children. One of them is 2 search bars. The second search bar `TagSearch` is supposed to render results from tag creation. What I'm trying to do is pass data from `Student` where the tags live, and pass them up to the App component in order to inject them into my Fuse instance in order for them to be searched. I have tried to create a function `update` in App.js and then pass it down to Student.js in order for the tags to update in the parent when a user searches the tags. For some reason, I'm getting a TypeError that states `update` is not a function.

I put in console logs to track where the tags appear. The tags appear perfectly fine in Student.js, but when I console log them in App.js, the tags just appear as an empty array which tells me they aren't being properly passed up the component tree from Student.js to App.js.

// App.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import Fuse from "fuse.js";
import Student from "./components/Student";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import TagSearch from "./components/TagSearch";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [query, updateQuery] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const [tagQuery, setTagQuery] = useState("");
  console.log("tags from app: ", tags);

  const getStudents = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const url = `private url for assignment`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      setStudents(response.data.students);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
  };

  const fuse = new Fuse(students, {
    keys: ["firstName", "lastName"],
    includeMatches: true,
    minMatchCharLength: 2,
  });

  const tagFuse = new Fuse(tags, {
    keys: ["text", "id"],
    includesMatches: true,
    minMatchCharLength: 2,
  });

  function handleChange(e) {
    updateQuery(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleTags(e) {
    setTagQuery(e.target.value);
  }

  const results = fuse.search(query);
  const studentResults = query ? results.map((s) => s.item) : students;

  const tagResults = tagFuse.search(tagQuery);
  const taggedResults = tagQuery ? tagResults.map((s) => s.item) : tags;

  const update = (t) => {
    t = tags; // changed this to make sure t is tags from this component's state
    setTags(t);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getStudents();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return "Loading ...";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main>
        <Search query={query} handleChange={handleChange} />
        <TagSearch query={tagQuery} handleTags={handleTags} />
        {studentResults &&
          studentResults.map((s, key) => <Student key={key} students={s} update={update} />)}
        {taggedResults &&
          taggedResults.map((s, key) => (
            <Student key={key} students={s} update={update} />
          ))}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

// Student.js

```
import Collapsible from "../components/Collapsible";
import findAverage from "../helpers/findAverage";
import Styles from "../styles/StudentStyles";

const KeyCodes = {
  comma: 188,
  enter: 13,
};

const delimiters = [KeyCodes.comma, KeyCodes.enter];

const Student = ({ students, update }) => {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const collapse = () => {
    setIsOpened(!isOpened);
  };

  const handleDelete = (i) => {
    const deleted = tags.filter((tag, index) => index !== i);
    setTags(deleted);
  };

  const handleAddition = (tag, i) => {
    setTags([...tags, tag]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    update(tags);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Styles>
      <div className="student-container">
        <img src={students.pic} alt={students.firstName} />
        <div className="student-details">
          <h1>
            {students.firstName} {students.lastName}
          </h1>
          <p>Email: {students.email}</p>
          <p>Company: {students.company}</p>
          <p>Skill: {students.skill}</p>
          <p>Average: {findAverage(students.grades)}</p>
          <Collapsible
            students={students}
            delimiters={delimiters}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            handleAddition={handleAddition}
            isOpened={isOpened}
            tags={tags}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={collapse}>+</button>
    </Styles>
  );
};

export default Student;
```

Comment: What I notice immediately is that the `Student` components created when there are search results are not passed an update function. Yet, the `useEffect` will still call `update` on the first render of them.

Comment: @CoryHarper so I'm confused. Should I wrap the search results in `App.js` with the update function, then pass the update function, and leave the useEffect?

Comment: Do a sanity check, `console.log(update)` on your `Student` component

Comment: I think what @Cory Harper meant is to simply pass `update` as a prop there.

Comment: you can simply add a callback function and when you send the data from `student` to the `app`, that callback function will be triggered and then change the state of the parent inside that callback

Comment: @k-wasilewski I'm not following. Pass update where? 
@RohanNaik I'm also not understanding where I should do this because update is being consoled out as `undefined`

Comment: When you map `studentResults`, you don't pass your `update` function down to `Student` components, that's all.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm I meant exactly what @k-wasilewski said. There is a condition under which right now you are rendering `Student` components without an update function as a prop. Those components are still calling `update` when they mount, but the function is undefined.

Comment: Ok so I passed `update` to the `studentResults` and updated the useEffect, I'll edit it in the original post.

Comment: So the list isn't updating when I search in the tags with the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to call `update` function every time you update `tags` in `Student`. Something like this:

```
const handleDelete = (i) => {
    const deleted = tags.filter((tag, index) => index !== i);
    setTags(deleted);
    update(deleted);
  };

  const handleAddition = (tag, i) => {
    let result = tags;
    result.push(tag);
    setTags(result);
    update(result);
  };
```

In this way, every time you change `tags` in `Student`, you will update `App` state.

An alternative could be use `useEffect` deps list. In `Student`, modify `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    update(tags);
  }, [tags]);
```

This means that, every time `tags` will update, `useEffect` will be triggered and `update` function will be called.

Comment: I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when i added this. I will say the useEffect is still useEffect(() => update(tags), [])

Comment: So you adopted my first suggestion. Precisely, which map is failing? I'm asking you becase, as I can see from your code, you don't call `.map` function in tags array. May I ask you anotehr thing? If you put a console.log in `App` `update` function, do you receive some values from `Student`?

Comment: So when I put in the `tags` in the useEffect brackets, it breaks with the .map error, but when I leave it blank, i get no errors, but the results don't update either.